# Read a list of files, apply function and rewrite with same name

Tags: r, csv

I have a set of csv files with duplicate entries, which I needed to remove and rewrite the files with same name and format.

Here is what I have done so far,

```
filenames<-list.files(pattern =".csv") 
datalist <-lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F)})
unique.list <- lapply(datalist,unique)
```

And I'm stuck with separating the data frames in the list and rewriting with same name. There is a more of a similar question, I tried hours but couldn't understand the proceedings.

Comment: The `voice of experience` says be certain that you create of a copy of the directory containing the files first, and keep one copy as the sacrosant originals. Just saying.

Answer (score 4):

I'd definitely use a `for` loop. Shhhhhh, don't tell anyone I said that. Why? Three reasons...

1. You want to call `write.csv` for it's side-effect, not it's return value, i.e. you want a file to be written to disk. Use `*apply` when you want a return value from your function.
2. The main bottle neck will be disk I/O so I expect no performance overhead using a `for` loop compared to using an `*apply` loop.
3. `*apply` functions will swallow memory on each iteration of the loop and are not guaranteed to free it up until all iterations have completed. In a `for` loop the memory is freed up at the start of the next iteration if you are overwriting objects inside the loop. If you are working with big `csv` files this could be an advantage. I will try and find a link to an answer where `for` solved a problem that `lapply` could not due to memory issues.

So all you need for my solution, given your de-duplicated data list is...

```
for( i in 1:length( filenames ) ){
  write.csv( unique.list[[i]] , filenames[[i]] )
}
```

[**Here is an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740495/1478381) where a `for` loop was required because the `lapply` equivalent ran into memory allocation errors.

Comment: Haha, the side note about `for` loops alone is worth a +1 ;-) good argumentation!

Comment: @flowla lol I sometimes think `for` loops are maligned. They have specific use cases where (I believe) they are the *right* solution.

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to test it right now, here is an approach that does all the required stuff within the `lapply` loop. The revised data is returned and stored as a list in the variable called `datalist`.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern =".csv") 

datalist <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  # Import data
  tmp <- read.csv(file = x, header = F)

  # Remove duplicated entries
  if (any(duplicated(tmp)))
    tmp <- tmp[-which(duplicated(tmp)), ]

  # Write output
  write.csv(tmp, x)

  # Return revised data
  return(tmp)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `mapply` :

```
mapply(function(filename, data) write.csv(data, file=filename), 
       filenames,
       unique.list)
```

Beware that if you don't modify `filenames`, this will overwrite your original data files.

`mapply` will return an empty list by default. As you only use the function for its side effect, you can wrap it up inside `invisible` if you prefer :

```
 invisible(mapply(function(filename, data) write.csv(data, file=filename), 
           filenames,
           unique.list))
```