# Looping to create and compute within multiple datasets

Tags: r, for-loop

I feel there is likely better ways to do this that I am unaware of. I do this a lot for multiple sets of similar data. What are some of the other ways I could structure this data so that it is fast and easy to read?

```
indices <- c("indexA", "indexB", "indexC")

for(i in 1:length(indices)){
  index <- indices[i]

  #This line reads CSV of the given index in the loop.
  eval(parse(text=paste0(index, " <- ",
                      "read.csv('data/", index, ".csv', skip=8)")))

  # This line does some type of computation using the newly imported data set
  eval(parse(text=paste0(index, "$newColumn <- ", 
                     index, "[1, 'Column.D']")))

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using a `for` loop here to read in data files, but using `eval()` and `parse()` is unnecessary. Use the provided tools. Best to keep your results in a single list (in this case it seems a list of `data.frame`s...

```
indices <- c("indexA", "indexB", "indexC")

#  Pre-allocate your result vector
ll <- vector( mode = "list" , length = length(indices) )

for(i in 1:length(indices)){
  index <- indices[i]

  #  Read file into 'temporary'  object that will get overwritten in next loop iteration
  tmp <- read.csv( paste0( "data/", index , ".csv" ) , skip=8 )

  #  Do some processing on it
  tmp$newColumn <- tmp[ 1 , 'Column.D']

  #  Store result in list vector
  ll[[i]] <- tmp
}
```

---

You may also consider `list.files()` if you want to process all the files in a directory, and you can supply a `pattern` argument which is a `regexp` to limit the names of the files you select, e.g. to select all files called `index*` where `*` is a letter from `A`-`Z`...

```
fls <- list.files( path = "data" , pattern = "index[A-Z]" , full.names = TRUE )
for( i in fls ){
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this answer. Is it acceptable to replace the last line with 'assign(index, tmp)'? Are there reasons I would prefer the list vector?

Comment: @rrbest absolutely! The idea behind keeping them in a list is just to not clutter up your workspace with lots of objects. Also keeping them in a list means you can easily apply a function to the list such as `lapply` to process all `data.frame`s at once. It is easier to use lots of objects held in a list, than individually, once you are comfortable working with lists.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with your objects.  If you are going to be applying the same analysis to all your objects, then definitely agree with @SimonO'Hanlon.  If you're going to be manually inspecting and browsing your objects (and there aren't too many of them), you're better of assigning them to the global env.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with `sapply`, which saves you having to reconstruct the index.  I first define the function that does the work, then use `sapply` to create the data.frames, and finally, I assign those data.frames to the variable names defined in `indices` with `list2env` (note that `sapply` will return a list of the three data frames, with each item named by `indices`, which is why this works).

```
indices <- c("indexA", "indexB", "indexC")

my_fun <- function(index) {   # this does the work
  df <- read.csv(paste0("data/", index, ".csv"), skip=8)
  transform(df, newColumn = Column.D)
}    
list2env(                     # assign to global env
  sapply(indices, my_fun, simplify=F),  # apply fun, returns list of 3 data frames
  envir=globalenv()
)
```

This will leave you with three data frames named as per `indices` in your global environment:

```
ls()
# [1] "indexA"  "indexB"  "indexC"  "indices" "my_fun"
```

Comment: `*apply` family functions are not always better for this kind of operation. R will not free up memory consumed by reading in and processing each of the files as it finishes with each one until the whole function has run. This does not happen using the `for` loop (which I also expect to be faster in this case, but admittedly I haven't benchmarked).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon is this specifically for reading files, or generally?  If the latter, my impression was that any unused reference upon completion of each function execution should be released (if needed).  Also, I just like that in the `apply` style the `list2env` step is so easy and part of the flow, that I don't have to initialize the target vector, etc.  It's just cleaner to write.

Comment: Specifically for reading in files. I always use a `for` loop for this. [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740495/1478381) would not work with `lapply` because it kept running out of memory. The `for` loop worked like a charm though.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, this is interesting, though the example you give seems to suggest that it's not just for reading in files, right (I don't see any files)?  If so that seems like a major problem with `*apply`.  I'm surprised I haven't heard this before.  Is the problem there that the `formula` is created inside the function which somehow prevents the function from being nuked because it is the enclosure of the formula (though it shouldn't since the formula should also be removed)?