# how to perform nls fro three matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, regression

If we have these matrix as example:

```
    x=matrix(runif(50 ),5,5)
    z=matrix(runif(60 ),5,5)
    y=exp(0.5*x+0.2*z+0.3)^1
```

the values in these three matrix change form one day to another so I have two years (daily,x1,x2,x3,etc)of these matrix(speaking of my real data)
to fit this equation `y=exp(s1x+s2x+s3)^s4`
use normal `Nls` as:

```
        fit <- nls(y ~ exp(s1*x+s2*z+s3)^s4,
             data = data,
             start = list(s1 = 0.5, s2 = 0.2, s3 = 0.3,s4=1))
```

but my problem is that I want to do this fit for all corresponding values in three matrix for example start  taking values from:

```
                   > use all values of x1[1,1], x2[1,1],.....etc
                  [1] 0.3617776 .......etc
                   > and the corresponding form z1[1,1], z2[1,1].....etc
                 [1] 0.5544851 .......etc
                   > y1[1,1], y2[1,1],etc .....
                 [1] 1.807213 .......etc
```

Find the fit parameters then do the same for all other corresponding values. Finally I get a matrix with, for example, values of `s1`, another matrix for `s2` etc….

Any help is appreciated(Note: I have to use it as it is and not to linearise it or use `lm.fit` or `lm`)

Comment: You can't estimate `s1`, `s2`, `s3`,and `s4` from a single `(y,x,z)` triplet. You would need multiple observations. I can't understand how you think this would work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to use a matrix-exponential (rather that what `exp()` will return which is elementwise.) I ask because the notation `exp(M)^1` suggests something other than what `exp(M)` would deliver.

Answer (score 2):

I think the x,y,z as matrices are throwing you off. As stated by MrFlick in the comment you need multiple observations to perform the regression. Here is an example of nlm applied to a simple 3d normal surface with some noise.

You need a n-by-3 matrix of observations in the 3d space. Here I make some noisy points along a Gaussian curve and rotate it to form a surface.

This example uses the [rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) package.

```
library(rgl)

z_rotate <- function(mat,rads){
    rot.mat <- matrix(c(cos(rads),-sin(rads),0,
                    sin(rads),cos(rads),0,
                    0, 0, 1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    mat %*% rot.mat
}

x <- seq(-2,2,0.1)
x <- x + rnorm(length(x),sd=0.5)
y <- seq(-2,2,0.1)
#y <- y + rnorm(length(y),sd=0.5)
z <-  0.5*exp(-x^2/2 + (-y^2/2)) + rnorm(1,sd=0.6)

m <- as.matrix(cbind(x,y,z))
```

now the matrix m is just the initial points about the normal curve.

```
points <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(1:8,function(n){z_rotate(m,n*(pi/8))}))
colnames(points) <- c("x","y","z")
```

The previous command just calls the rotate function then appends the results as new rows in the matrix.

Now the points matrix represents the observations to be approximated with our nlm function.

```
> dim(points)
[1] 328   3
```

Now we can view these points in 3d with RGL.

```
plot3d(points[,1],points[,2],points[,3],type='s',size=0.3)
```

[image]

Use nlm to fit a function that approximates this data.

```
fit <- nls(z ~ s1*exp(-s2*x^2 + (-s3*y^2)) +s4,
        data = data.frame(points),
        start = list(s1 = 0.3, s2 = 0.3, s3 = 0.3, s4=0.3),
        #trace=TRUE,
        control = list(warnOnly=TRUE))
```

It produces this fit:

```
> fit
Nonlinear regression model
  model: z ~ s1 * exp(-s2 * x^2 + (-s3 * y^2)) + s4
   data: data.frame(points)
     s1      s2      s3      s4 
 0.5000  0.5000  0.5000 -0.1084 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.493e-31

Number of iterations till stop: 50 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 0.05046
Reason stopped: number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
```

We can see that it recovers the values we had, namely 0.5 for the coefficients when we compare the formulas.

```
z <-  0.5*exp(-x^2/2 + (-y^2/2)) + rnorm(1,sd=0.6)

z ~ s1*exp(-s2*x^2 + (-s3*y^2)) +s4
```

I know its a toy example but it might give you some ideas as to how to set up your data. I think you will need to structure your data in an n-by-3 observations matrix to be able to do your regression with nlm.

Comment: @hyat, again, these are lists of matrices. You need to determine what it is that you are fitting. If you need to do multiple fits then you need to structure you data differently. These are 3-by-15 matrices. Would it make sense to flatten these into a single list (one each for x, y, z) or is the matrix structure important to your problem?

Comment: @hyat, I think you are misunderstanding how regression works. The output of a regression models is the set of coefficients that go into the model. The outputs from nlm are the s1,s2,s3,s4 that apply to your formula. These are single numbers each so 4 in total there are no matrices for output.

Comment: Or are you saying you need to do 15 different regressions, one for each entry in the matrix? Do you have 15 sets of 700-by-3 observations?

Comment: Ok in that case I think you know what you need to do. You will have to structure your data as n-by-3 for each regression you want to do then loop over this data using nlm each time. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737334/all-possible-regression-in-r-saving-coefficients-in-a-matrix) may give you some ideas on looping and performing multiple regressions.